# How do I copy children from one parent to another using SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have two models Map and Image. For the sake of simplicity I'll just put the relationships in question:

```
class Map(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'maps'

    id = Column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True
        )

    images = relationship(
        'Image',
        uselist=True,
        cascade='all, delete-orphan',
        passive_deletes=True
        )


class Image(Model):
    __tablename__ = 'images'

    id = Column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True
        )

    map_id = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey(
            'maps.id',
            onupdate='CASCADE',
            ondelete='CASCADE'
            ),
        index=True,
        nullable=False
        )

    map = relationship(
        'Map',
        back_populates='images'
        )
```

I was trying to copy images from one model instance to another like this

```
new_map = Map()
# do some stuff
old_map = Map.query.get(some_id)
new_map.images = old_map.images
session.add(new_map)
session.commit()
```

This had the unexpected behavior (for me) of changing the map_id column on the original table rows, rather than creating a new object that's a copy or the old one with map_id assigned to the new map. I'm sure this behavior makes sense but I was having trouble searching for my desired behavior.

How do I copy a list of children to another parent, creating new rows and preserving the old?

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to make an updates to an existing database rows while inserting new rows at the same time. is that what you want?

Comment: I'm essentially creating a second version of an existing record from maps, including entries in the related table images. It's meant to be a working copy of an existing record that can be changed without changing the original. I know I can just create new rows and go through and copy each column but I was hoping that there was a convenience method I could employ.